# Jquery class applying in multiple rows make it apply in just one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

**Problem:**
my problem is very simple.

the class `input-test`  it is applying in mutiples rows.

this class should just apply once in the row i am editing.
right now if i click in multiple rows to edit the class `input-test` applies, this should not happen.

**to test:**

click in the button edit in table 1

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/56/

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataUrl = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bSiXDKRpMy?indent=2';
var options = [
    { key : '1', value : 'n1' },
    { key : '2', value : 'n2' },
    { key : '3', value : 'n3' }
  ];

var rowCache = [];

function mouseUp(event)
{
  var ctrl = $(document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).filter('input.border-highlight');

  if (ctrl.length > 0 && rowCache.length > 0)
  {
    var el = rowCache[0];
    var data = el.row.data();

    if (data.length > 0)
    {
      ctrl.val(data[0].member);
      el.row.remove().draw();
    }
  } 

  rowCache = [];
  // after dropped cell
  $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').removeClass('border-highlight');

  //removing bg of cell
  $('#example tr td').removeClass('name-highlight-hover animated  bounceIn');

  $('#example tr td input').removeClass('animation-examples three animated  bounceIn');

  if ($("#example tr td:nth-child(2) input").hasClass("name-highlight-hover")) {
    $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('input-test');
  //$('#example tr td input').css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "60%"})
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $('#example');
  var dataTable = null;

  $('body').mouseup(mouseUp);

  $table.on('mousedown', 'td .fa.fa-minus', function(e) {
    dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
     $('div.alert.alert-success').hide();
    $('div.pull-right.warning').hide();
    $('div.pull-right').hide();
    $('div.alert.alert-danger').fadeIn("slow");
  });

  $table.on('mousedown.edit', 'i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o', function(e) {
    enableRowEdit($(this));
  });

  $table.on('mousedown', 'input', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $table.on('mousedown.save', 'i.fa.fa-save', function(e) {
    updateRow($(this), true); // Pass save button to function.
  });

  $table.on('mousedown', '.select-basic', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  dataTable = $table.DataTable({
         ajax: dataUrl,
        order: [[ 3, "asc" ]],
       "bPaginate": false,
      columns: [{
      data: 'order'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'place'
    }, {
      data: 'delete'
    }]
  });

  $table.css('border-bottom', 'none')
        .after($('<div>').addClass('addRow')
          .append($('<button>').attr('id', 'addRow').text('Add New Row')));

  // Add row
  $('#addRow').click(function() {
    var $row = $("#new-row-template").find('tr').clone();
    dataTable.row.add($row).draw();
    // Toggle edit mode upon creation.
    enableRowEdit($table.find('tbody tr:last-child td i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o'));
     $('button.btn.btn-primary').attr('disabled', false);
    $('div.alert.alert-success').hide();
    $('div.alert.alert-warning').fadeIn("slow");
    $('div.pull-right').hide();
    $('div.pull-right.warning').show();
  });

  $('#btn-save').on('click', function() {
    updateRows(true); // Update all edited rows
  });

  $('#btn-cancel').on('click', function() {
    updateRows(false); // Revert all edited rows
  });

  function enableRowEdit($editButton) {
    $editButton.removeClass().addClass("fa fa-save");
    var $row = $editButton.closest("tr").off("mousedown");

    $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
      enableEditText($(this))
    });

    $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
      enableEditSelect($(this))
    });
  }

  function enableEditText($cell) {
    var txt = $cell.text();
    $cell.empty().append($('<input>', {
      type : 'text',
      value : txt
    }).data('original-text', txt));
  }

  function enableEditSelect($cell) {
    var txt = $cell.text();
       $('button.btn.btn-primary').attr('disabled', false);
    $('div.alert.alert-danger').hide();
    $('div.alert.alert-success').hide();
    $('div.alert.alert-warning').fadeIn("slow");
    $('div.pull-right').hide();
    $('div.pull-right.warning').show();
    $cell.empty().append($('<select>', {
      class : 'select-basic'
    }).append(options.map(function(option) {
      return $('<option>', {
        text  : option.key,
        value : option.value
      })
    })).data('original-value', txt));
}

  function updateRows(commit) {
     $table.find('tbody tr td i.fa.fa-save').each(function(index, button) {
      updateRow($(button), commit);
    });
  }

  function updateRow($saveButton, commit) {
    $saveButton.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-pencil-square-o');
    var $row = $saveButton.closest("tr");

    $row.find('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(this).find('input');
      $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-text'));
    });
     $('div.alert.alert-warning').hide();
     $('div.alert.alert-success').fadeIn("slow");
     $('div.pull-right').hide();

      var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
      members.filter(':not(:has(input))').removeClass('name-highlight-hover');  

    $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(this).find('select');
      $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-value'));
    });
  }
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ckoulMvqHm?indent=2';
    table = $('#example2').DataTable({
      ajax: url,
      order: [
        [0, "desc"]
      ],
      rowReorder: {
        dataSrc: 'member',
        selector: 'tr'
      },
      "bPaginate": false,
      columns: [{
        data: 'member'
      }],
             "drawCallback": function(settings) {

                 setTimeout(function() {
                    //dragging
                     $('#example2 tr').draggable({
                         drag: function(event) {

                             var ctrl = $(document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).filter('#example tr td:nth-child(2),input.border-highlight');

                             $('.name-highlight-hover').removeClass('name-highlight-hover');
                             if (ctrl.length > 0) {
                                 ctrl.addClass('name-highlight-hover animated  bounceIn ');
                                  var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
                                  members.filter(':not(:has(input))').removeClass('name-highlight-hover animated  bounceIn');


                             }


                         }
                     });

                 })

             }
    });

    table.on('mousedown', 'tbody tr', function () {
      var $row = $(this);

      var r = table.rows(function (i, data) {
        return data.member == $row.children().first().text();
      });

      if (r[0].length > 0)
      {

        $row.parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $row.addClass('highlight');
        $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('border-highlight');
        $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('animation-examples three');

        // $row.parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        // $row.addClass('highlight');
        // $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('border-highlight');

        var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
        // members.filter(':has(input)').addClass('border-highlight');
        // members.find('input').addClass('border-highlight');  
        members.filter(':not(:has(input))').removeClass('border-highlight'); 




      }     

      rowCache.push({ row: r });
    });

    });

});
```

Comment: Possibly, just before you add the class, add: `$(".input-test").removeClass("input-test");$('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('input-test');`  alternatively you need to use the context of the element (`ctrl`) you've moused-up on, possibly `$(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test");` - but, tbh, there's so much code here, most of which is going to be irrelevant to the question, that's it's too difficult to wade through.

Comment: sorry freedoom, i am very novice on this, i cant do it :(, could you provide a jsfiddle?  thank you

Comment: Try this: replace the `addClass("input-test")` line with `$(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test");` and see what happens.

Comment: perfect, works, can you answer? i will give the points, thank you man, really thanks.

Comment: glad you got it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
$('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('input-test');
```

applies the class to the column on all rows.

In order to ensure you only select the one you're interested in, you'll need to either filter the selection or use the context of the element you've located, ie:

```
$(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test");
```

which takes the ctrl located earlier, goes up to the row it is on and then finds the relevant cell and input on just that row.

To remove `input-test` from other rows, you could also add:

```
$(".input-test").removeClass("input-test");
```

depending on whether you want single select or multi-select.